# Inserting continued numbered list of paragraphs in openxml

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a word document with numbered list paragraph in it.
For example

1. List item
2. Google News is a news aggregator and app developed by Google. It presents a 
   continuous, customizable flow of articles organized from thousands of 
   publishers.
3. Paragraph 3.

My requirement is to continue to insert two more numbered lists 4., 5. etc paragraphs(with text). And also should retain the previous paragraph formatting.

With the current code the numbering list is starting from 1. instead of 4. Not getting where I am wrong.

```
NumberingDefinitionsPart numberingPart = Document.MainDocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart;
var abstractNumId = numberingPart.Numbering.Elements<AbstractNum>().Count() + 1;
AbstractNum abstractNum1 = new AbstractNum() { AbstractNumberId = abstractNumId };
abstractNum1.SetAttribute(new OpenXmlAttribute("w15", "restartNumberingAfterBreak", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml", "0"));

Paragraph paragraph15 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphMarkRevision = "005B5111", RsidParagraphAddition = "0012034F", RsidParagraphProperties = "005B5111", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "004A6864", ParagraphId = "555A4D6E", TextId = "49553577" };

ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties11 = new ParagraphProperties();
ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId11 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "ListParagraph" };
Level level2 = new Level() { LevelIndex = 6, TemplateCode = "04090019", Tentative = true };
StartNumberingValue startNumberingValue2 = new StartNumberingValue() { Val = 1 };
NumberingFormat numberingFormat2 = new NumberingFormat() { Val = NumberFormatValues.LowerLetter };

LevelJustification levelJustification2 = new LevelJustification() { Val = LevelJustificationValues.Left };

PreviousParagraphProperties previousParagraphProperties2 = new PreviousParagraphProperties();

NumberingProperties numberingProperties1 = new NumberingProperties();
NumberingLevelReference numberingLevelReference1 = new NumberingLevelReference() { Val = 0 };
NumberingId numberingId1 = new NumberingId() { Val = 4 };
LevelText levelText2 = new LevelText() { Val = "%7." };
level2.Append(startNumberingValue2);
level2.Append(numberingFormat2);
level2.Append(levelText2);
level2.Append(levelJustification2);
level2.Append(previousParagraphProperties2);

abstractNum1.Append(level2);

numberingProperties1.Append(numberingLevelReference1);
numberingProperties1.Append(numberingId1);

ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties8 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();
RunFonts runFonts54 = new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Arial", HighAnsi = "Arial", ComplexScript = "Arial" };
Color color1 = new Color() { Val = "626262" };
FontSize fontSize56 = new FontSize() { Val = "20" };
FontSizeComplexScript fontSizeComplexScript6 = new FontSizeComplexScript() { Val = "20" };
Shading shading1 = new Shading() { Val = ShadingPatternValues.Clear, Color = "auto", Fill = "FFFFFF" };

paragraphMarkRunProperties8.Append(runFonts54);
paragraphMarkRunProperties8.Append(color1);
paragraphMarkRunProperties8.Append(fontSize56);
paragraphMarkRunProperties8.Append(fontSizeComplexScript6);
paragraphMarkRunProperties8.Append(shading1);

paragraphProperties11.Append(paragraphStyleId11);
paragraphProperties11.Append(numberingProperties1);
paragraphProperties11.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties8);
BookmarkStart bookmarkStart1 = new BookmarkStart() { Name = "_GoBack", Id = "0" };
BookmarkEnd bookmarkEnd1 = new BookmarkEnd() { Id = "6" };

Run run45 = new Run() { RsidRunProperties = "005B5111" };

RunProperties runProperties41 = new RunProperties();
RunFonts runFonts55 = new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Arial", HighAnsi = "Arial", ComplexScript = "Arial" };
Color color2 = new Color() { Val = "626262" };
FontSize fontSize57 = new FontSize() { Val = "20" };
FontSizeComplexScript fontSizeComplexScript7 = new FontSizeComplexScript() { Val = "20" };
Shading shading2 = new Shading() { Val = ShadingPatternValues.Clear, Color = "auto", Fill = "FFFFFF" };

runProperties41.Append(runFonts55);
runProperties41.Append(color2);
runProperties41.Append(fontSize57);
runProperties41.Append(fontSizeComplexScript7);
runProperties41.Append(shading2);
Text text21 = new Text();
text21.Text = "agency or by the Public Records";
run45.Append(runProperties41);
run45.Append(text21);

Run run46 = new Run();

RunProperties runProperties42 = new RunProperties();
RunFonts runFonts56 = new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Arial", HighAnsi = "Arial", ComplexScript = "Arial" };
Color color3 = new Color() { Val = "626262" };
FontSize fontSize58 = new FontSize() { Val = "20" };
FontSizeComplexScript fontSizeComplexScript8 = new FontSizeComplexScript() { Val = "20" };
Shading shading3 = new Shading() { Val = ShadingPatternValues.Clear, Color = "auto", Fill = "FFFFFF" };

runProperties42.Append(runFonts56);
runProperties42.Append(color3);
runProperties42.Append(fontSize58);
runProperties42.Append(fontSizeComplexScript8);
runProperties42.Append(shading3);
Text text22 = new Text();
text22.Text = ".";

run46.Append(runProperties42);
run46.Append(text22);

paragraph15.Append(paragraphProperties11);
paragraph15.Append(bookmarkStart1);
paragraph15.Append(bookmarkEnd1);
paragraph15.Append(run45);
paragraph15.Append(run46);
Document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(paragraph15);
```

Comment: Did my Answer help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is using `new NumberingId() { Val = 4 };` If you want to continue an existing list, get the `NumberingId` from that list (any paragraph, but simplest/logically you'd probably use the last) and use it.

If you use the Productivity Tool to look at the underlying Open XML you'll see something like this in document.xml. Note that this is the Word Open XML that defines two paragraphs - both are members of the same numbering sequence (List).

```
<w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
      <w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="5"/></w:numPr>
      <w:tabs><w:tab w:val="right" w:pos="8789"/></w:tabs></w:pPr>
         <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">This is a numbered line</w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
      <w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="5"/></w:numPr>
      <w:tabs><w:tab w:val="right" w:pos="8789"/></w:tabs></w:pPr>
         <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">Another numbered line</w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
```

Note two things: `<w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>` and `<w:numId w:val="5"/>`

The first of these defines how the numbering looks - in this case it's a built-in style. You don't need to do anything with this, but it's "good to know".

The second tells Word where to look up the numbering sequence in numbering.xml. This is what keeps a list "together". This element corresponds to the `NumberingId` in the SDK.

You can see that both paragraphs above use the same ID. If they're numbered 1 and 2, and the user switches them (by dragging, for example), the numbering will adjust. What was 1 becomes 2 and vice versa. This is only possible because Word handles numbering in this manner. If you were to create a paragraph, put it between these two, with the same numbering ID, the paragraph numbering would again adjust automatically to 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Hi I struggled a lot with this approach and couldn't find any working solution. So now I changed the code .

Comment: I dont know how add solution here as it says I exceed by 1400 characters in the comment section.

Comment: @user4895544 If you mean you've solved the problem and want to post your solution use the ANSWER box, rather than a comment. Not only can that hold more information, you can also format it.